# Homepage not changing to desired page

Tags: wordpress, static, cpanel, rewriting

My site is hosted on Godaddy though I have been thinking of transferring it to Namecheap (thinking that the host platform might be the problem) but here's. The problem

My client site which I manage - was built using WpBakery theme. We've redesigned a new page which we want to replace the old main front static page with, but I have gone through all the possible route - settings > reading > change static front page selection to desired page - but after saving the changes it still reverts back to the old / Home page.

2 - Appearance > customize > Home page setting > same selection and after publishing - it's still same issue. Did all I ever think. I could buy it's not changing to the page I want.

What could be the real issue here?

Comment: When you say it reverts back to the old page, does it revert in the setting too? Or the setting shows your new page but hitting the url shows the old page.

Comment: Hi please I'm yet to resolve this. Any help I can get would be appreciated.